# calling fortran subroutine from c and reading a grid file

Tags: c, grid, fortran, calling-convention

I'm trying to call one Fortran subroutine (`gpt2_1w.f`) from one C file (`main.c`). The problem is that in one part of the Fortran code it needs to open and read some values from the grid file called `gpt2_1wA.grd`. The C program can call some basic level Fortran subroutines without any problem but when it comes to the some grid or Ascii file attached to the Fortran one, it gives an error like undefined reference to `_gfortran_at_open...etc`. I'm using codeblocks and cygwin at the same time. Maybe I'm missing some libraries or have to declare the grid file inside the C code in some way... I'm not sure.

Here is the C code in which I'm calling the Fortran subroutine:

**main.c**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
        #include <math.h>

        #define Pi                                  3.14159265358979
        #define d2r                                 (Pi/180.)
        #define r2d                                 (180./Pi)

    //fortran sub//    
void gpt2_1w_(double *dmjd, double *dlat,double *dlon, double *hell, double *nstat, double *it, double *p, double *T, double *dT, double *Tm, double *e, double *ah, double *aw, double *la, double *undu);

        int main()
        {
            double dmjd = 55055;
            double lat = 36.256;
            double lon = 32.589;
            double hell = 812.253;
            double nstat = 1.0;
            double it = 0.0;

        double dlat=lat*d2r;
        double dlon=lon*d2r;


            double p, T, dT, Tm, e, ah, aw, la, undu;

    //calling fortran sub// 
gpt2_1w_(&dmjd, &dlat, &dlon, &hell, &nstat, &it, &p, &T, &dT, &Tm, &e, &ah, &aw, &la, &undu);

              printf( "pressure = %15.8f\n", p );
            printf( "Mean Temp = %15.8f\n", T );

             return 0;

        }
```

Here the whole Fortran code:

```
            subroutine gpt2_1w (dmjd,dlat,dlon,hell,nstat,it,
     .              p,T,dT,Tm,e,ah,aw,la,undu)

      implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)

      double precision lagrid(64800,5),la(64800),lal(4)

      dimension vec(44)

      dimension dlat(64800),dlon(64800),hell(64800)
      dimension dT(64800),T(64800),p(64800),e(64800),
     .          ah(64800),aw(64800),undu(64800),Tm(64800)

      dimension pgrid(64800,5),Tgrid(64800,5),Qgrid(64800,5),
     .          dTgrid(64800,5),u(64800),Hs(64800),ahgrid(64800,5),
     .          awgrid(64800,5),Tmgrid(64800,5)

      dimension undul(4),Ql(4),dTl(4),Tl(4),pl(4),ahl(4),awl(4),Tml(4)
     .          ,el(4) 

      dimension indx(4) 

      character line*80


c% mean gravity in m/s**2
      gm = 9.80665d0;
c% molar mass of dry air in kg/mol
      dMtr = 28.965d-3
c% universal gas constant in J/K/mol
      Rg = 8.3143d0

      pi = 3.1415926535d0

c% change the reference epoch to January 1 2000
      dmjd1 = dmjd-51544.5d0

c% factors for amplitudes
      if (it.eq.1) then ! constant parameters
        cosfy = 0.d0
        coshy = 0.d0
        sinfy = 0.d0
        sinhy = 0.d0
      else 
        cosfy = dcos(dmjd1/365.25d0*2.d0*pi)
        coshy = dcos(dmjd1/365.25d0*4.d0*pi)
        sinfy = dsin(dmjd1/365.25d0*2.d0*pi)
        sinhy = dsin(dmjd1/365.25d0*4.d0*pi)
      end if

c% read gridfile
      open(11,file='gpt2_1wA.grd')

c% read first comment line
      read (11,'(a80)') line

c% loop over grid points
      do n = 1,64800

        !% read data line
        read (11,*) vec
        pgrid(n,1:5)  = vec(3:7)           !% pressure in Pascal
        Tgrid(n,1:5)  = vec (8:12)         !% temperature in Kelvin
        Qgrid(n,1:5)  = vec(13:17)/1000.d0 !% specific humidity in kg/kg
        dTgrid(n,1:5) = vec(18:22)/1000.d0 !% temperature lapse rate in Kelvin/m
        u(n)          = vec(23)            !% geoid undulation in m
        Hs(n)         = vec(24)            !% orthometric grid height in m
        ahgrid(n,1:5) = vec(25:29)/1000.d0 !% hydrostatic mapping function coefficient, dimensionless
        awgrid(n,1:5) = vec(30:34)/1000.d0 !% wet mapping function coefficient, dimensionless
        lagrid(n,1:5) = vec(35:39)         !% water vapour decrease factor, dimensionless
        Tmgrid(n,1:5) = vec(40:44)         !% weighted mean temperature, Kelvin

      end do
      close (11)

c% loop over stations
      do k = 1,nstat

        !% only positive longitude in degrees
        if (dlon(k).lt.0.d0) then
          plon = (dlon(k) + 2.d0*pi)*180.d0/pi
        else
          plon = dlon(k)*180.d0/pi
        end if
        !% transform to polar distance in degrees
        ppod = (-dlat(k) + pi/2.d0)*180.d0/pi 

        !% find the index (line in the grid file) of the nearest point
        ipod = floor(ppod+1.d0) 
        ilon = floor(plon+1.d0)

        !% normalized (to one) differences, can be positive or negative
        diffpod = ppod - (ipod - 0.5d0)
        difflon = plon - (ilon - 0.5d0)
        !% added by HCY
        if (ipod.eq.181) then
          ipod = 180
        end if
        !% added by GP
        if (ilon.eq.361) then
          ilon = 1
        end if
        if (ilon.eq.0) then
          ilon = 360
        end if

        !% get the number of the corresponding line
        indx(1) = (ipod - 1)*360 + ilon

        !% near the poles: nearest neighbour interpolation, otherwise: bilinear
        !% with the 1 degree grid the limits are lower and upper (GP)
        ibilinear = 0
        if ((ppod.gt.(0.5d0)).and.(ppod.lt.(179.5d0))) then 
          ibilinear = 1          
        end if          

        !% case of nearest neighborhood
        if (ibilinear.eq.0) then

          ix = indx(1);

          !% transforming ellipsoidal height to orthometric height
          undu(k) = u(ix)
          hgt = hell(k)-undu(k)

          !% pressure, temperature at the height of the grid
          T0 = Tgrid(ix,1) + 
     .         Tgrid(ix,2)*cosfy + Tgrid(ix,3)*sinfy + 
     .         Tgrid(ix,4)*coshy + Tgrid(ix,5)*sinhy
          p0 = pgrid(ix,1) + 
     .         pgrid(ix,2)*cosfy + pgrid(ix,3)*sinfy+ 
     .         pgrid(ix,4)*coshy + pgrid(ix,5)*sinhy

          !% specific humidity
          Q = Qgrid(ix,1) + 
     .        Qgrid(ix,2)*cosfy + Qgrid(ix,3)*sinfy+ 
     .        Qgrid(ix,4)*coshy + Qgrid(ix,5)*sinhy

          !% lapse rate of the temperature
          dT(k) = dTgrid(ix,1) + 
     .            dTgrid(ix,2)*cosfy + dTgrid(ix,3)*sinfy+ 
     .            dTgrid(ix,4)*coshy + dTgrid(ix,5)*sinhy 

          !% station height - grid height
          redh = hgt - Hs(ix)

          !% temperature at station height in Celsius
          T(k) = T0 + dT(k)*redh - 273.15d0

          !% temperature lapse rate in degrees / km
          dT(k) = dT(k)*1000.d0

          !% virtual temperature in Kelvin
          Tv = T0*(1+0.6077d0*Q)

          c = gm*dMtr/(Rg*Tv)

          !% pressure in hPa
          p(k) = (p0*exp(-c*redh))/100.d0

          !% hydrostatic coefficient ah 
          ah(k) = ahgrid(ix,1) + 
     .            ahgrid(ix,2)*cosfy + ahgrid(ix,3)*sinfy+ 
     .            ahgrid(ix,4)*coshy + ahgrid(ix,5)*sinhy

          !% wet coefficient aw
          aw(k) = awgrid(ix,1) + 
     .            awgrid(ix,2)*cosfy + awgrid(ix,3)*sinfy + 
     .            awgrid(ix,4)*coshy + awgrid(ix,5)*sinhy

          !% water vapour decrease factor la - added by GP
          la(k) = lagrid(ix,1) + 
     .            lagrid(ix,2)*cosfy + lagrid(ix,3)*sinfy + 
     .            lagrid(ix,4)*coshy + lagrid(ix,5)*sinhy

          !% mean temperature of the water vapor Tm - added by GP
          Tm(k) = Tmgrid(ix,1) + 
     .            Tmgrid(ix,2)*cosfy + Tmgrid(ix,3)*sinfy + 
     .            Tmgrid(ix,4)*coshy + Tmgrid(ix,5)*sinhy

          !% water vapor pressure in hPa - changed by GP
          e0 = Q*p0/(0.622d0+0.378d0*Q)/100.d0  !% on the grid
          e(k) = e0*(100.d0*p(k)/p0)**(la(k)+1) ! % on the station height - (14) Askne and Nordius, 1987

        else !% bilinear interpolation

          ipod1 = ipod + int(sign(1.d0,diffpod))
          ilon1 = ilon + int(sign(1.d0,difflon))
          !% changed for the 1 degree grid (GP)
          if (ilon1.eq.361) then
             ilon1 = 1
          end if
          if (ilon1.eq.0) then
            ilon1 = 360
          end if

          !% get the number of the line
          indx(2) = (ipod1 - 1)*360 + ilon   !% along same longitude
          indx(3) = (ipod  - 1)*360 + ilon1  !% along same polar distance
          indx(4) = (ipod1 - 1)*360 + ilon1  !% diagonal

          do l = 1,4

            !% transforming ellipsoidal height to orthometric height:
            !% Hortho = -N + Hell
            undul(l) = u(indx(l))
            hgt = hell(k)-undul(l)

            !% pressure, temperature at the height of the grid
            T0 = Tgrid(indx(l),1) + 
     .           Tgrid(indx(l),2)*cosfy + Tgrid(indx(l),3)*sinfy + 
     .           Tgrid(indx(l),4)*coshy + Tgrid(indx(l),5)*sinhy
            p0 = pgrid(indx(l),1) + 
     .           pgrid(indx(l),2)*cosfy + pgrid(indx(l),3)*sinfy + 
     .           pgrid(indx(l),4)*coshy + pgrid(indx(l),5)*sinhy

            !% humidity 
            Ql(l) = Qgrid(indx(l),1) + 
     .              Qgrid(indx(l),2)*cosfy + Qgrid(indx(l),3)*sinfy + 
     .              Qgrid(indx(l),4)*coshy + Qgrid(indx(l),5)*sinhy

            !% reduction = stationheight - gridheight
            Hs1 = Hs(indx(l))
            redh = hgt - Hs1

            !% lapse rate of the temperature in degree / m
            dTl(l) = dTgrid(indx(l),1) + 
     .               dTgrid(indx(l),2)*cosfy + dTgrid(indx(l),3)*sinfy + 
     .               dTgrid(indx(l),4)*coshy + dTgrid(indx(l),5)*sinhy 

            !% temperature reduction to station height
            Tl(l) = T0 + dTl(l)*redh - 273.15d0

            !% virtual temperature
            Tv = T0*(1+0.6077d0*Ql(l))  
            c = gm*dMtr/(Rg*Tv)

            !% pressure in hPa
            pl(l) = (p0*exp(-c*redh))/100.d0

            !% hydrostatic coefficient ah
            ahl(l) = ahgrid(indx(l),1) + 
     .               ahgrid(indx(l),2)*cosfy + ahgrid(indx(l),3)*sinfy +
     .               ahgrid(indx(l),4)*coshy + ahgrid(indx(l),5)*sinhy

            !% wet coefficient aw
            awl(l) = awgrid(indx(l),1) + 
     .               awgrid(indx(l),2)*cosfy + awgrid(indx(l),3)*sinfy + 
     .               awgrid(indx(l),4)*coshy + awgrid(indx(l),5)*sinhy

            !% water vapor decrease factor la - added by GP
            lal(l) = lagrid(indx(l),1) + 
     .               lagrid(indx(l),2)*cosfy + lagrid(indx(l),3)*sinfy + 
     .               lagrid(indx(l),4)*coshy + lagrid(indx(l),5)*sinhy

            !% mean temperature of the water vapor Tm - added by GP
            Tml(l) = Tmgrid(indx(l),1) + 
     .               Tmgrid(indx(l),2)*cosfy + Tmgrid(indx(l),3)*sinfy + 
     .               Tmgrid(indx(l),4)*coshy + Tmgrid(indx(l),5)*sinhy

            !% water vapor pressure in hPa - changed by GP
            e0 = Ql(l)*p0/(0.622d0+0.378d0*Ql(l))/100.d0 !% on the grid
            el(l) = e0*(100.d0*pl(l)/p0)**(lal(l)+1.d0)  !% on the station height  (14) Askne and Nordius, 1987

          end do

          dnpod1 = abs(diffpod) !% distance nearer point
          dnpod2 = 1.d0 - dnpod1   !% distance to distant point
          dnlon1 = abs(difflon)
          dnlon2 = 1.d0 - dnlon1

          !% pressure
          R1 = dnpod2*pl(1)+dnpod1*pl(2)
          R2 = dnpod2*pl(3)+dnpod1*pl(4)
          p(k) = dnlon2*R1+dnlon1*R2

          !% temperature
          R1 = dnpod2*Tl(1)+dnpod1*Tl(2)
          R2 = dnpod2*Tl(3)+dnpod1*Tl(4)
          T(k) = dnlon2*R1+dnlon1*R2

          !% temperature in degree per km
          R1 = dnpod2*dTl(1)+dnpod1*dTl(2)
          R2 = dnpod2*dTl(3)+dnpod1*dTl(4)
          dT(k) = (dnlon2*R1+dnlon1*R2)*1000.d0

          !% water vapor pressure in hPa - changed by GP
          R1 = dnpod2*el(1)+dnpod1*el(2)
          R2 = dnpod2*el(3)+dnpod1*el(4)
          e(k) = dnlon2*R1+dnlon1*R2

          !% hydrostatic
          R1 = dnpod2*ahl(1)+dnpod1*ahl(2)
          R2 = dnpod2*ahl(3)+dnpod1*ahl(4)
          ah(k) = dnlon2*R1+dnlon1*R2

          !% wet
          R1 = dnpod2*awl(1)+dnpod1*awl(2)
          R2 = dnpod2*awl(3)+dnpod1*awl(4)
          aw(k) = dnlon2*R1+dnlon1*R2

          !% undulation
          R1 = dnpod2*undul(1)+dnpod1*undul(2)
          R2 = dnpod2*undul(3)+dnpod1*undul(4)
          undu(k) = dnlon2*R1+dnlon1*R2

          !% water vapor decrease factor la - added by GP
          R1 = dnpod2*lal(1)+dnpod1*lal(2)
          R2 = dnpod2*lal(3)+dnpod1*lal(4)
          la(k) = dnlon2*R1+dnlon1*R2

          !% mean temperature of the water vapor Tm - added by GP
          R1 = dnpod2*Tml(1)+dnpod1*Tml(2)
          R2 = dnpod2*Tml(3)+dnpod1*Tml(4)
          Tm(k) = dnlon2*R1+dnlon1*R2

        end if

      end do

      end subroutine
```

and this is the structure of the grid file that I'm reading from Fortran and wanted to be read from C as well:

```
%  lat    lon   p:a0    A1   B1   A2   B2  T:a0    A1   B1   A2   B2  Q:a0    A1    B1    A2    B2 dT:a0    A1   B1   A2   B2    undu       Hs   h:a0      A1      B1      A2      B2    w:a0      A1      B1      A2      B2  lam:a0      A1      B1      A2      B2    Tm:a0    A1   B1   A2   B2              
  89.5    0.5 101472   114  431 -221 -128 259.2 -13.3 -6.1  2.4  0.3  1.64 -1.63 -0.68  0.51  0.35   1.3   7.0  3.1 -0.5  1.9   15.05     0.00 1.1870 -0.0351 -0.0128  0.0053  0.0034  0.5796  0.0084  0.0093  0.0005  0.0042  1.6682 -0.7893 -0.3329  0.0769 -0.1810    254.8  -9.8 -4.3  2.2  1.1    
  89.5    1.5 101471   114  431 -220 -128 259.2 -13.3 -6.1  2.4  0.3  1.64 -1.63 -0.68  0.51  0.35   1.3   7.0  3.1 -0.5  1.9   15.04     0.00 1.1870 -0.0351 -0.0128  0.0053  0.0034  0.5796  0.0084  0.0092  0.0005  0.0042  1.6682 -0.7894 -0.3321  0.0761 -0.1812    254.8  -9.8 -4.3  2.2  1.1    
  89.5    2.5 101471   114  431 -220 -128 259.2 -13.3 -6.1  2.4  0.3  1.64 -1.63 -0.68  0.51  0.35   1.3   7.0  3.1 -0.5  1.9   15.04     0.00 1.1870 -0.0351 -0.0128  0.0053  0.0034  0.5796  0.0084  0.0093  0.0005  0.0042  1.6690 -0.7890 -0.3318  0.0757 -0.1813    254.8  -9.8 -4.3  2.2  1.1
```

I'm getting some errors related with reading grid file from C:

```
||=== Build: Debug in gpt2_1w (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===| 
obj\Debug\gpt2_1w.o||In function `gpt2_1w_':|
gpt2_1w.f|167|undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_open'| 
gpt2_1w.f|170|undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_read'|    
gpt2_1w.f|170|undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character'|
gpt2_1w.f|170|undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_read_done'|
gpt2_1w.f|176|undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_read'| 
gpt2_1w.f|176|undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_array'| 
gpt2_1w.f|176|undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_read_done'| 
gpt2_1w.f|189|undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_close'|
```

I'd be appreciate for any help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you also show the declaration of all the dummy variables of `gpt2_1w()` (in the Fortran code)? Also, are `pgrid(:,:)` and `Tgrid(:,:)` etc local variables of this routine? If you wish to get all the values from the file back into C, I guess you need to pass arrays from C to Fortran (now scalars are passed instead).

Comment: As for the linkage issue, attaching `-lgfortran` may help (though not sure how to do it in CodeBlocks...)